# DeleteConfirmationButton does not disappear when using custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, button

I have a custom TableViewCell (without Interface Builder) when I use the swipe gesture to trigger the DeleteConfirmationButton to appear and then touch it the button disappears as usual.

But when I set the whole TableView in editing mode with the default edit button:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];
```

and then touch the DeleteConfirmationButton it only gets dark red and don't dissapears.

Any ideas?

PS: Is it possible to don't show the button when using the swipe gesture (so it only is available in editing mode)?

EDIT: To get an idea what I mean (I'm only using the delete button to clear the stars)

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/940415/Screenshot%202010.11.21%2016.42.34.png]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the delete button you can try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // delete stars
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
}
```

The answer to your PS is yes. You can use something along the lines of:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!tableView.editing) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
    return  UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: the PS works well thanks :) but when i try to reload the row it simply dissapears...when i scroll down and then back up it shows up again

Comment: also the left button stays vertical and when i retry to delete the deletebutton is already drak red...

Comment: It sounds strange that the row disappears. Granted I only tested it with the sample core data navigation controller template but it worked just fine. Are you perhaps changing any properties that is used to sort the list when resetting the stars? That could maybe explain the disappearing act.

Comment: Could it be related to your implementation of the custom delete button? Have you tried if it works with the stock delete button?

Comment: The only thing i changed about the deletebutton is in rootviewcontroller.m --> - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"-";
}

Comment: This now works for me...but i don't really like the solution :S GSRatingCell cell = (GSRatingCell)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; [cell setRating:0]; [cell setEditing:NO]; [cell setEditing:YES];